# 'No valid symbol found' in Google Sentencepiece in Python

Tags: python, c++, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to finetune a german GPT-2 model on Pytorch using this repo: https://github.com/lopuhin/transformer-lm

The first time I have trained it on a 1MB txt file UTF-8 encoded. Everything went well, and it was working with no issues. Now, I am using the same txt file just cleaned (removed some spaces, some weird punctuations etc... nothing major) that I have saved and encoded in the exact same way as the previous one.

When trying to use it for training, I get this error:

```
bpe_model_trainer.cc(166) LOG(INFO) Updating active symbols. max_freq=0 min_freq=0
bpe_model_trainer.cc(257) LOG(INFO) Added: freq=0 size=40520 all=209 active=134 piece=ungsmanagements
bpe_model_trainer.cc(257) LOG(INFO) Added: freq=0 size=40540 all=189 active=114 piece=▁Gesundheitsver
bpe_model_trainer.cc(257) LOG(INFO) Added: freq=0 size=40560 all=169 active=94 piece=▁Problemunkraut
bpe_model_trainer.cc(257) LOG(INFO) Added: freq=0 size=40580 all=149 active=74 piece=▁Wirtschaftslei
bpe_model_trainer.cc(257) LOG(INFO) Added: freq=0 size=40600 all=129 active=54 piece=iskriminierenden
bpe_model_trainer.cc(166) LOG(INFO) Updating active symbols. max_freq=0 min_freq=0
bpe_model_trainer.cc(257) LOG(INFO) Added: freq=0 size=40620 all=109 active=34 piece=▁Bundesbeauftrag
bpe_model_trainer.cc(257) LOG(INFO) Added: freq=0 size=40640 all=89 active=14 piece=▁Nahrstoffbelast
bpe_model_trainer.cc(241) LOG(WARNING) No valid symbol found
trainer_interface.cc(508) LOG(INFO) Saving model: sp-model.model
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/sp-train", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('lm', 'console_scripts', 'sp-train')()
  File "/content/gdrive/My Drive/testing-gpt2/transformer-lm/lm/data.py", line 62, in sp_train
    f'--character_coverage={args.character_coverage}',
RuntimeError: Internal: /sentencepiece/src/trainer_interface.cc(499) [(trainer_spec_.vocab_size()) == (model_proto->pieces_size())]
```

From what I gather, the error is related to Google Sentencepiece which does not find any valid symbol. I am not sure what it means at all. I have tried changing the encoding of the file, as well as deleting german special characters, but nothing works. I have also tried to run Sentencepiece with different parameters such as character_coverage (as explained here https://github.com/google/sentencepiece#train-sentencepiece-model) but nothing helped.

I am not even sure I understand the error, so any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!